# Rename first column in specific way in awk

Tags: awk, text-processing

This is my input file

```
900 mgdg molecules in water t= 953400.00000 step= 635600000
177255
    1BGL     C5    1   4.977  15.059   2.068
    1BGL     H5    2   5.025  15.020   2.158
    1BGL     O5    3   4.881  14.948   2.052
...(a lot of lines between)
...
    4LIN    HI216099   1.909  19.279   7.886
    4LIN    HI316100   1.849  19.417   7.987 (the last line, which I want to modify is 116102)
...
...
20389SOL    HW177254   0.325   8.307   3.850
20389SOL    HW277255   0.245   8.235   3.957
   5.75588  25.65343  12.14665
```

My output file should look like

```
900 mgdg molecules in water t= 953400.00000 step= 635600000
177255
    1MGD     C5    1   4.977  15.059   2.068
    1MGD     H5    2   5.025  15.020   2.158
    1MGD     O5    3   4.881  14.948   2.052
...(a lot of lines between)
...
  900MGD    HI216099   1.909  19.279   7.886
  900MGD    HI316100   1.849  19.417   7.987 (the last line, which I want to modify is 116102)
...
...
20389SOL    HW177254   0.325   8.307   3.850
20389SOL    HW277255   0.245   8.235   3.957
   5.75588  25.65343  12.14665
```

I want to modify only first column in 100 files. every 129 lines I add value. For example lines 3-131 in the first column have 1MGD, then lines 132-260 - 2MGD and again until 116102 lines.

This is my script, but it didn't work

```
#!/bin/bash
for index in {1..100} 
do
    awk 'BEGIN { grp = 129 }
        {if (NR>=3 && NR<=116102) { 

        for (i=1; i<=116102; i++) {
                    $1 = (int($i/grp)+1)"MGD"
        }
        }; print $0}' eq15_$index.gro | tee eq2_15_$index.gro
done
```

Could you help me?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] that includes concise, testable sample input and expected output. To make the example **minimal** you would, for example, change 100 files to 2 files, 129 lines to 3 lines, 116102 lines to 8 lines, etc so you can post 2 sample input files that are no more than 10 lines each (without any `...`s) but which reproduce your problem and you can scale yourself later to apply your real values. i.e. give us something that clarifies your requirements AND we can test a potential solution against.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk 'NR>=3 && NR<=116102{ x=int((NR-3)/129+1); $1=x"MGD" }1' file
```

---

Testing:

You have to set the start-end `NR` and the divisor to define it. For example for this test file:

```
900 mgdg molecules in water t= 953400.00000 step= 635600000
177255
    1BGL     C5    1   4.977  15.059   2.068
    1BGL     H5    2   5.025  15.020   2.158
    1BGL     O5    3   4.881  14.948   2.052
    1BGL     C5    1   4.977  15.059   2.068
    1BGL     H5    2   5.025  15.020   2.158
    1BGL     O5    3   4.881  14.948   2.052
    1BGL     O5    3   4.881  14.948   2.052
    4LIN    HI216099   1.909  19.279   7.886
    4LIN    HI316100   1.849  19.417   7.987 (the last line, which I want to modify
20389SOL    HW177254   0.325   8.307   3.850
20389SOL    HW277255   0.245   8.235   3.957
   5.75588  25.65343  12.14665
```

to modify lines 3-11 every 3 lines:

```
> awk 'NR>=3 && NR<=11{ x=int( (NR-3)/3+1);$1 = x"MGD"}1' file
900 mgdg molecules in water t= 953400.00000 step= 635600000
177255
1MGD C5 1 4.977 15.059 2.068
1MGD H5 2 5.025 15.020 2.158
1MGD O5 3 4.881 14.948 2.052
2MGD C5 1 4.977 15.059 2.068
2MGD H5 2 5.025 15.020 2.158
2MGD O5 3 4.881 14.948 2.052
3MGD O5 3 4.881 14.948 2.052
3MGD HI216099 1.909 19.279 7.886
3MGD HI316100 1.849 19.417 7.987 (the last line, which I want to modify
20389SOL    HW177254   0.325   8.307   3.850
20389SOL    HW277255   0.245   8.235   3.957
   5.75588  25.65343  12.14665
```

---

Also, never use a `bash` loop with `awk` on the same file inside. It can be done with one `awk`.